# Стилизация ошибки required

Tags: html, css, html5

Сейчас при ошибке вылетает вот такое окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне, например, заменить этот восклицательный знак, сменить шрифт внутри и т.д

Comment: Никак. Если нужно индивидуальный стиль, то прийдеться делать самому.

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145